# PHP get all possible lines (between two words)

Tags: php

i want to get all possible lines between two words for example i got following news

A wildlife centre in Norfolk says it is struggling to cope after more than 100 seal pups were found injured following last week's tidal surge.

The East Winch centre, near King's Lynn, has launched a crisis appeal because a baby seals are too young in the sea to fend for themselves.

RESULT

i want to get any lines between A and in

Possible lines would be

1).  A wildlife centre in
2).  a baby seals are too young in

i have tried it but unable to do that. please help me... here is my tried code.

```
<?php

$string="A wildlife centre in Norfolk says it is struggling to cope after more than 100 seal pups were found injured following last week's tidal surge.The East Winch centre, near King's Lynn, has launched a crisis appeal because a baby seals are too young in the sea to  fend for themselves.";

preg_match_all('/(a)(.*?)(in)/', $string, $matches);    

foreach($matches[2] as $value) 
echo preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value).'<br />'; 

?>
```

regards,

Comment: You could add the `i` flag to make your search case-insensitive: `preg_match_all('/(a)(.*?)(in)/i', $string, $matches);`

Comment: one more question @RobM. how we can add special characters in search instead of a or in... special characters like ()#$/\|..ect...i tried this too but it doesn't work. thanks.

Comment: Removing the `?` from `(.*?)` should match special characters, but you can always be explicit: `([A-Za-z\s_-\(\)\|\#\$\/\]*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the i flag to make your search case-insensitive:

`preg_match_all('/(a)(.*)(in)/i', $string, $matches);`